# My Application is in Php, Using XAMPP SQL

Tags: sql, php, phpunit

SQL have one field i.e. Date

My application's UI have three drop down

1. Day
2. Month
3. Year

I inserted its value using CONCAT

```
$c3date=  @trim(stripslashes($_POST['c3year']. '-' . $_POST['c3month'] . '-' . $_POST['c3day']));
```

and values are stored in Database.

How can I view the 'Day', 'Month' and 'Year'? I need separate values of 'Day', 'Month' and 'Year'.

Comment: Ananth, I understand that you're using phpunit, but this does seem like a general php programming question. I'll ping the SO mods to see if they'd accept this.

Comment: So this is indeed off-topic and would be migrated to SO. But it would get closed as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9054998/330057 so I'll just point you there and close this here.

Answer (score 0):

If your date field value is stored in a field of SQL Database (as mentioned by you), then you can view the same using simple SQL queries either using [Datepart](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datepart.asp) (Month, Date) or [Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781946/getting-only-month-and-year-from-sql-date) YEAR (YourDate), MONTH (YourDate), DAY (YourDate);

both will return you the desired values.

Comment: How can retrieve the values in php from sql..Php have three separate drop down fields are  Day, month, year,but sql i stored value is Date